# Problem: Run project locally using Pycharm with App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, pycharm, localhost

Hey guys, I'm facing a problem when i want to run a web project locally using in PyCharm using App Engine. After running the project on local.dev:8080 the web project does not appear see the image below.
[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIS0l.png)

So please if anyone could help ?

However I'm satisfying all the requirements"
 - Python 2.7
 - Google App Engine SDK

Thanks

Comment: It is a Flask App brother

Comment: you dont have a trusted certificate on your machine, try `http://` instead of `https://`

Answer (score 0):

It is something related with the SSL that is using a self signed certificate. I found that this is a Firefox [issue](https://www.xolphin.com/support/Error_messages/Error_-_ssl_error_rx_record_too_long) please try with another browser

As is mentioned please use HTTP or another browser, even you can try to run your flask application manually in order to check his functionality.